# Finder content search for exact string

Tags: finder, search

In Finder, I have searched for files with a content which contains a string "<tableview ".

Result list has files which content contains strings like " < tableview.frame.height"

It looks like my search string is not treated as exact string search.

How can I force Finder to search for exact strings?

[image]

[image]